# SQL Functions with Variable Numbers of Arguments

Tags: postgresql, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION mleast(VARIADIC arr numeric[]) RETURNS numeric AS $$
    SELECT min($1[i]) FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT mleast(10, -1, 5, 4.4);
```

link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/xfunc-sql.html
Please kindly check: 35.4.5.
SQL Functions with Variable Numbers of Arguments
The part I understand is:

- Example like  FROM generate_series(2,4)
- min function.

What i don't understand:

```
  min($1[i])
     g(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

It easier to understand when running in steps and passing actual value:

```
-- 1.generate subscripts from 1 to n(where n is number of elements)
SELECT *
FROM generate_subscripts('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[], 1) g(i); 

+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+

-- 2. get actual value at specific subscript
SELECT  ('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[])[i]
FROM generate_subscripts('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[], 1) g(i);

+---------+
| numeric |
+---------+
|      10 |
|      -1 |
|       5 |
|     4.4 |
+---------+

-- 3. find minimum value from entire set
SELECT  MIN(('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[])[i])
FROM generate_subscripts('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[], 1) g(i);

+-----+
| min |
+-----+
|  -1 |
+-----+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=263c0692113107d7cb8b8e24d1df71f1)**

`g(i)` - is an alias for result set from function call and returned value

`min($1[i])` - aggregate min function over array provided as first parameter with subscript i

---

```
SELECT * -- g.i
FROM generate_subscripts('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[], 1) g(i); 
+---+
| i | -- "i" as the column alias
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
SELECT *
FROM generate_subscripts('{10, -1, 5, 4.4}'::numeric[], 1); 
+---------------------+
| generate_subscripts |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
|                   2 |
|                   3 |
|                   4 |
+---------------------+
```